# How can I find time interval between 00:00:00 and 23:28:05 without date in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

So I have this table where I've got two times for each line, but no date and need to get the interval between those two, all is fine when it's:

11:00:00 - 09:38:54

Returns: 01:21:06

As there's no dates, times are stored in "time without time zone" format.

The problem arises when the time enters the next day and the hour becomes 00h, as there's no date the interval will something absurd like -22:58:21

Example:

00:00:00 - 22:59:01

Returns: -22:59:01

00:00:00 - 22:44:06

Returns: -22:44:06

Is there anyway to make SQL understand 00:00:00 as 24:00:00 for the sake of math without date?

The hours only range between 8 and 0, and nothing from the previous day goes further than 0h30, a simple case for "00h" solves it, but I can't make SQL understand 00h as 24h so far. Any ideas?

Comment: You need to add more detail to this question about the two time fields involved and how they are being used. In particular is one considered the start and the other the end time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like:

```
select '24:00:00'::time - '22:59:01'::time;
 ?column? 
----------
 01:00:59
```

**UPDATE**

If the `00:00:00` is coming from somewhere you can't modify in place then:

```
select time_fld from time_test ;
 time_fld 
----------
 00:00:00
 01:30:00

select coalesce(nullif(time_fld, '00:00:00'::time), '24:00:00') from time_test;
 coalesce 
----------
 24:00:00
 01:30:00
```

Comment: This is ALMOST it, it solves 99% of the problem already, there's around 5 cases that have the time as just a bit over 00:00, like 00:04:53. How can I switch that 00h for 24?

Comment: You can't `select '24:04:53'::time; ERROR:  date/time field value out of range: "24:04:53"`. You will need to add an example to your question for this case.

Comment: I had only seem the first field ranging up to 00h00, but there's a just a couple cases in the second row that went above it, like 00:06:34. I solved it just using the '24:00:00'::time - (first_row - second_row). That solved it. Thanks.